# What does the recovery tag mean?

Tags: support, status-deferred, tags

What does the [recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/recovery) tag mean, if anything? Or is it one of those overly broad tags whose questions haven't yet been recategorized into sub-categories?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it should be a synonym for [data-recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery), but I can't create the synonym that way round as [recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/recovery) is used more times.

It could also be used for [recovery-partition](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/recovery-partition) (there are 16 questions [with both tags](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/recovery+partition)), so just creating the synonym blind might be a bad idea. It might need a manual retagging of each question.

I've made a start removing it from questions that are tagged both [recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/recovery) **and** [data-recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if [recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/recovery) is really just related to [data-recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery). I may want to recover from something that is not data related. I would rather get more opinions on this before creating the synonym.